# How to enable Intel Extension for Pytorch(IPEX) in my python code?

Tags: python, pytorch, intel, intel-python, intel-pytorch

I would like to use Intel Extension for Pytorch in my code to increase overall performance. Referred this GitHub(https://github.com/intel/intel-extension-for-pytorch) for installation.

Currently, I am trying out a hugging face summarization PyTorch sample(https://github.com/huggingface/transformers/blob/master/examples/pytorch/summarization/run_summarization.py). Below is the trainer API used for training.

```html
   # Initialize our Trainer
    trainer = Seq2SeqTrainer(
        model=model,
        args=training_args,
        train_dataset=train_dataset if training_args.do_train else None,
        eval_dataset=eval_dataset if training_args.do_eval else None,
        tokenizer=tokenizer,
        data_collator=data_collator,
        compute_metrics=compute_metrics if training_args.predict_with_generate else None,
    )
```

I am not aware of enabling Ipex in this code. Can anyone help me with this?

Thanks in Advance!

Answer (score 3):

The key changes that are required to enable IPEX are:

```
    #Import the extension right after import torch.
    import intel_extension_for_pytorch as ipex
    #Apply the optimizations to the model for its datatype:
    model = ipex.optimize(model)
```

And lastly, convert the imperative model to a graph model. For TorchScript, invoke torch.jit.trace() and torch.jit.freeze(). For TorchDynamo, invoke torch.compile(model, backend="ipex").
For CPUs, please check out - https://intel.github.io/intel-extension-for-pytorch/cpu/latest/tutorials/getting_started.html.
For GPUs, please check out - https://intel.github.io/intel-extension-for-pytorch/xpu/latest/tutorials/getting_started.html.

To learn more about PyTorch Optimizations from Intel, please check out - https://www.intel.com/content/www/us/en/developer/tools/oneapi/optimization-for-pytorch.html#gs.6l2068.

Comment: When I try `input_ids = input['input_ids'].to(memory_format=torch.channels_last)`, I'm getting the following error:
`RuntimeError: required rank 4 tensor to use channels_last format`

Answer (score 1):

For enabling Intel Extension for Pytorch you just have to give add this to your code,

```
import intel_extension_for_pytorch as ipex
```

Importing above extends PyTorch with optimizations for extra performance boost on Intel hardware

After that you have to add this in your code

```
model = model.to(ipex.DEVICE)
```

Answer (score 1):

First, you will need to subclass the Trainer object and create an custom optimizer as described in the [Hugging Face docs](https://huggingface.co/docs/transformers/main_classes/trainer)

The APIs for using `intel_extension_for_pytorch` has changed a bit, to use the library, you just have to do:

```py
import intel_extension_for_prytorch as ipex

model, optimizer = ipex.optimize(model, optimizer=optimizer)
```

Answer (score 1):

Currently, Transformers 4.21 has support IPEX.[IPEX Graph Optimization with JIT-mode](https://huggingface.co/docs/transformers/v4.21.1/en/perf_infer_cpu#pytorch-jitmode-torchscript)

```
python run_qa.py
    --model_name_or_path csarron/bert-base-uncased-squad-v1 \
    --dataset_name squad \
    --do_eval \
    --max_seq_length 384 \
    --doc_stride 128 \
    --output_dir /tmp/ \
    --no_cuda \
    --use_ipex \
    --jit_mode_eval
```